# Stikked Docker Container - Disable Captcha

Tags: docker

Has anyone dockerized this app?

https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked

I am pretty far along. Was able to get a mySQL container up and running and get the site up on my local.  But no matter how I try to disable the captcha, I get the error:
[image]

I have tried disabling captcha in the `docker-php-entrypoint` file, in the `stikked.php.dist`, and I flat out tried running the `docker run` command with `-e STIKKED_ENABLE_CAPTCHA=false` (ive tried single and double quotes).

Steps to recreate my setup:

*From my docker server*

1.Spin up mysql container
`docker run --rm --name stikdb --network=bridge -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=stikdb -e MYSQL_USER=stikuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=stikpassword -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=stikrootpassword --hostname stikdb mysql:5.7`

2.Checkout claudehohl/Stikked git project
 `git clone https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked.git`

3.Build Stikked container
`docker build -t stikked .`

4.Spin up container with parameters
`docker run --rm --link stikdb:stikdb --network bridge -e STIKKED_ENABLE_CAPTCHA=false -e STIKKED_BASE_URL=http://192.168.0.50:9999/ -e STIKKED_DB_HOSTNAME=stikdb -e STIKKED_DB_DATABASE=stikdb -e STIKKED_DB_USERNAME=stikuser -e STIKKED_DB_PASSWORD=stikpassword -p 9999:80 stikked`

*From my desktop*

5.Go to http://192.168.0.50:9999/ and try to create a new paste

Answer (score 0):

**Current Hack In Place.**

I am leaving this note in case anyone stumbles on this issue and it never gets correctly answered.

I was able to modify a couple files to disable the captcha functionality and remove it from displaying.

1. Edit `/htdocs/application/controllers/Main.php`
   Remove lines 465-469 (including 469)

```
               array(
                    'field' => 'captcha',
                    'label' => 'Captcha',
                    'rules' => 'callback__valid_captcha',
                ) ,
```

*This made captcha no longer necessary to submit a pastebin but the form remained on the page

2. Edit `/htdocs/themes/default/views/defaults/paste_form.php`
   Remove lines 109-123

```
<?php if($this->config->item('enable_captcha') && $this->session->userdata('is_human') === null){ ?>
        <div class="item_group">
            <div class="item item_captcha">
                <label for="captcha"><?php echo lang('paste_spam'); ?>
                    <span class="instruction"><?php echo lang('paste_spam_desc'); ?></span>
                </label>
<?php if($use_recaptcha){
    echo recaptcha_get_html($recaptcha_publickey, null, stristr(base_url(), 'https'));
} else { ?>
                <img class="captcha" src="<?php echo site_url('view/captcha'); ?>?<?php echo date('U', time()); ?>" alt="captcha" width="180" height="40" />
                <input value="" type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" tabindex="2" maxlength="32" />
<?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

*This made the form go away from the page

Rebuild the Docker image and fire up the container!

I know this is a hack that doesn't solve why the code wasn't disabling the captcha but desperate times...

Answer (score 0):

Set `STIKKED_ENABLE_CAPTCHA=` or `STIKKED_ENABLE_CAPTCHA=0` in environment.

What happens is the values are somehow dynamically loaded and quoted as strings into config.php and this sets `$config['enable_captcha'] = 'false'`. 'false' is considered true in PHP. So an empty string or 0 will do the trick.